# Strong normalization and concatenative programming language

Tags: reference-request, normal-forms

Are there some references about concatenative programming languages with the normalization property?

Comment: I am not sure if strong normalization applies to concatenative PLs. AFAIK, most concatenative PLs are stack-oriented, and normalization is a property of rewrite systems. $\lambda$-calculi are rewrite systems so we talk about their normalization, but non-functional PLs in general are not. I am not sure if strong normalization would apply to concatenative PLs unless we find a functional, concatenative programming language.

Comment: @xuq01 There are functional concatenative languages that can be described with rewrite systems. Few examples are Joy, Cat, and Awelon.

Comment: OK, I learned something new :-)